# Count Down Counter/ Timer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

please can anyone show me how to implement a countdown timer for starting a game in cocos2d for the iPhone.

What I mean is that on pressing "play" a new scene comes up with the numbers "3", "2", "1"  displayed and then the word "GO!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From "cocos2d Best Practices":

> Try NOT to use Cocoa’s NSTimer. Instead use cocos2d’s own scheduler.

So this is example of using cocos2d’s scheduler to animate your label, even with some effect.

In @interface:

```
int timeToPlay;
CCLabelTTF * prepareLabel;
CCLabelTTF * timeoutLabel;
CCMenu *menu;
```

In init:

```
timeToPlay=4;

CGSize s = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
prepareLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Prepare to play!" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:40];
prepareLabel.position = ccp(s.width/2.0f, 150);

timeoutLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"3" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:60];
timeoutLabel.position = ccp(s.width/2.0f, 90);

[self addChild:prepareLabel];
[self addChild:timeoutLabel];

timeoutLabel.visible=NO;
prepareLabel.visible=NO;

...
CCMenuItem *Play = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"PLAY" 
                                           target:self 
                                         selector:@selector(aboutToPlay:)];
...
```

aboutToPlay:

```
-(void) aboutToPlay: (id) sender {
    [self removeChild:menu cleanup:YES];
    timeoutLabel.visible=YES;
    prepareLabel.visible=YES;
    [self schedule: @selector(tick:) interval:1];
}
```

And tick:

```
-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt
{
    if(timeToPlay==1) [self play];
    else {
        timeToPlay--;
        NSString * countStr;

        if(timeToPlay==1)
        countStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GO!"];
        else
        countStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", timeToPlay-1];

        timeoutLabel.string = countStr;

        //and some cool animation effect
        CCLabelTTF* label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:countStr fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:60];

        label.position = timeoutLabel.position;
        [self addChild: label z: 1001];
        id scoreAction = [CCSequence actions:
                            [CCSpawn actions:
                              [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.4 scale:2.0],
                              [CCEaseIn actionWithAction:[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.4] rate:2],
                              nil],
                            [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
                              [self removeChild:label cleanup:YES];
                            }],
                            nil];
        [label runAction:scoreAction];

    }

}
```

Play:

```
-(void) play {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionSlideInL transitionWithDuration:0.4 scene:[GamePlay node]]];
}
```

Comment: thanks a million for your detailed answer and for giving a direct answer to my question. It works perfectly!

Comment: Don't forget to add `if ( self = [super init] )` block in the beginning of `init` method. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you require using cocos2d, by all means do it, however it'd be easier just doing it *without*. Set up a UILabel with the necessary outlets in IB, declare `countdownTimer` as an NSTimer object and then in your viewDidLoad or somewhere else significant:

```
     countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
     label.text = @"3";
     [countdownTimer fire];
```

and then then update the time:

```
- (void)updateTime {
     if ([label.text isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
          label.text = @"2";
     } else if ([label.text isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
          label.text = @"1";
     } else {
          label.text = @"GO!";
          [countdownTimer invalidate];
          //continue with app
     }
}
```

Haven't checked the validity of that code but it should get you going in the right direction!

Comment: :Thanks a lot for your reply. I will look at this and see how I can utilise it for cocos2d as that is what I am really after. Once again thanks a million.

Comment: @zaki remember that the big green check is there if you've found it's what you needed! :D

Comment: :All right not a problem but i am still waiting to see if I will get more responses or answers that are specific to Cocos2d. thanks